# What is the origin of the name 'dcommit' in git svn dcommit?

Tags: git, git-svn, dcommit

Does `dcommit` stand for Distributed Commit? Something else?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [this link](http://samv.github.io/blog/2007/02/10-An_introduction_to_gits.html), it stands for `Delta Commit`.  More specifically:

- The command to use is git svn
  dcommit. The d stands for delta
  (there used to be a git svn commit
  command that has since been renamed
  to git svn set-tree because its
  behaviour was considered a little
  'surprising' for first-time users).